# ALSA SOC_SINGLE_EXT_TLV control doesn't trigger events

Tags: events, alsa

I have declared an ALSA control :

```
static const struct snd_kcontrol_new deqx_digi_ana_audio_controls[] = {
SOC_SINGLE_EXT_TLV("Master Volume", 0, 0, 255, 0, master_get, master_put, master_tlv),
};
```

It shows up in alsamixer, which is great. But when I change the alsamixer "Master Volume" control, it doesn't trigger an ALSA control event. Normally the events show up using alsacontrol with the monitor command :

```
alsactl monitor
```

This is on Linux version 4.19.* on an embedded system.

Any suggestions on how to make ALSA fire the control command ?

Answer (score 0):

The master_put method has to return 1 for the ALSA control system to fire and event.